# DOS Batch Files and Variable Expansion

Tags: windows, batch-file

I need to write a DOS batch file which conceptually does this:

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET TARGET=c:\Temp\directory name with spaces\
FOR %%C IN (A B C D ) DO (
   copy "Setups\%%C\Release\%%C%Setup.msi"  "%%TARGET%\%%C"
   echo Similar commands ...
)
```

Where, for instance,

> Setups\A\Release\ASetup.msi would be copied to c:\temp\directory name with spaces\A\ASetup.msi

The problem I'm having is that the command processor parses this very counter-intuitively and doesn't produce the expected (or even a useful) result.
Is this possible in a single command file?

(I can do it with an auxilliary batch file - but that seems inelegant)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`call copy "Setups\%%C\Release\%%CSetup.msi"  "%TARGET%\%%CSetup.msi"`

1. You had a stray percentage sign in `%%C%Setup.msi`
2. Then a double percentage in `%%TARGET%` - you only need one.
3. You were missing Setup.msi from the end of the destination filename.

Note: I used call as well, by habit, even though you don't strictly need it in this example.

Comment: Thanks! I thought I'd tried that variation already - obviously I missed something.